# How to remove title from React Native Navigator?

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have a tab bar navigator (sliding horizontally) and is set to the bottom of the screen, I want to have the bar with only icons, no title, here is the current design:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
const AppTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Home',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Icon name="ios-home" style={{color: 'white'}} color={tintColor} size={24} />
            )
        }
    },
    Hot: {
        screen: SettingsScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Hot',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Icon name="ios-flame" style={{color: 'white'}} color={tintColor} size={24} />
            )
        }
    }
}, {
        order: ['Home', 'Hot'],
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        swipeEnabled: true,
        animationEnabled: true,
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: 'orange',
            inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
            style: {
                backgroundColor: '#4050B5',
                borderTopWidth: 0.5,
                borderTopColor: 'grey'
            },
            indicatorStyle: {
                height: 0
            },
            showIcon: true
        }
})
```

I want the tab bar without title, just icons, but if I remove tabBarLabel, it still gets the name from "Home: {" and "Hot: {", the only way I found to remove the title is to set tabBarLabel to space, empty does not work:

> tabBarLabel: ' '

but the result is terrible:

[image]

I want it in a way that the icons are barely touching the bottom of the screen, like the only padding is above and below the icon equally.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use

```
 tabBarLabel:() => {return null},
```

Comment: Perfect! Flawless result, exactly what I wanted, it even removed the reserved space for the title.

Comment: If this solution is worked for you then don't forgot to accept it ..  happy to help

Comment: I just couldn't accept before because it had time protection for accepting, you answered too fast haha

Answer (score 6):

You can use `showLabel` property of `tabBarOptions` to false.

Here is the link for the reference: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html

Comment: It didn't work, I tried using tabBarLabel and setting showLabel to false, then tried without tabBarLabel and still was showing, probably is a property to native tab navigator, I'm using react-navigation

Comment: It should work. You are using react-navigation v2 lib for Tab and the above link redirect you on the same docs.

Answer (score 3):

use tabBarShowLabel: false

```
<Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
      }}
>
..
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> `tabBarLabel:' '`, will not work as it is deprecated and replaced with the **"name"** property. i.e. compulsory. You can
> try adding white spaces.

For example :-

```
 <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        activeColor="#f0edf6"
        inactiveColor="#CBCFE1CC"
        barStyle={{backgroundColor: '#51C833'}}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name=" " //Single White Space
          component={Screen1}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="menu" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="  " //Double White Spaces
          component={Screen2}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="checkbox-outline"
                color={color}
                size={26}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

**Note -** *Adding multiple spaces will work but I would not recommend it for professional work.*