# How can I remove the title of each tab screen in React Navigation 5?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, vector, react-navigation, uitabbar

So, I've created a tabbar:

[image]

It works perfect, but how can I remove this titles under each of my Icons?

Comment: Which version of react-navigation you are using?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718974/how-to-remove-title-from-react-native-navigator

Answer (score 0):

```
 tabBarLabel:() => {return null},
```

easily with this option you can return nothing for title